# Else statement executing even though the if statement is true

Tags: python-3.x, search, graph, a-star, euclidean-distance

for school i am making an assignment, implementing astar search with the use of dictionaries. I have been trying a few things, but now i am stuck. in my first iteration the if statement *if f_next < f:* is true, so why does it not break out of the loop. It immediately goes to the else statement so my closed list contains both values from the if and else statement, how can i fix this. I have provided my code, some assignment information and the input below.

Given a grid-like graph, find the shortest path using A* between the two nodes with the maximum weight. Use the Euclidean as heuristic function, which is calculated between two points in a coordinate system (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) as follows:
d = p(x2 −x1)2 + (y2 −y1)2 (1) where, the nodes of the graph are represented as such points (see the input format below). You can assume that there exists a path between the two nodes with the maximum weight, and that all nodes have a unique weight.

Data format 1. The following is the input format expected by the algorithm for Task 1.
The program takes as input a list of nodes, represented as points in a coordinate system (e.g.,(x1,y1) and their weights separated by a ;.

In a new line the data-set of the graph edges are given following the pattern ”source node (xs,ys), end node (xe,ye), edge cost; ...”.

(x1), (y1), (weight1); ...(xn), (yn), (weightn);\n

(x1), (y1), (x2), (y2), (edgecost1); ...(xs), (ys), (xe), (ye), (edgecostm);\n

The expected output is the path from the start to the end node.
(xstart), (ystart)->(xi), (yi)...->(xend), (yend)\n

Input:

```
 0, 0, 193; 0, 1, 146; 0, 2, 121; 0, 3, 174; 0, 4, 144; 1, 0, 191; 1, 1, 123; 1, 2, 151; 1, 3, 126; 1, 4, 163; 2, 0, 182; 2, 1, 107; 2, 2, 109; 2, 3, 125; 2, 4, 165; 3, 0, 169; 3, 1, 149; 3, 2, 180; 3, 3, 199; 3, 4, 199; 4, 0, 160; 4, 1, 148; 4, 2, 123; 4, 3, 197; 4, 4, 156
 0, 0, 1, 0, 1; 0, 0, 0, 1, 1; 0, 1, 1, 1, 1; 0, 1, 0, 2, 1; 0, 2, 1, 2, 1; 0, 2, 0, 3, 1; 0, 3, 1, 3, 1; 0, 3, 0, 4, 1; 0, 4, 1, 4, 1; 1, 0, 2, 0, 1; 1, 0, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 2, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1, 2, 1; 1, 2, 2, 2, 1; 1, 2, 1, 3, 1; 1, 3, 2, 3, 1; 1, 3, 1, 4, 1; 1, 4, 2, 4, 1; 2, 0, 3, 0, 1; 2, 0, 2, 1, 1; 2, 1, 3, 1, 1; 2, 1, 2, 2, 1; 2, 2, 3, 2, 1; 2, 2, 2, 3, 1; 2, 3, 3, 3, 1; 2, 3, 2, 4, 1; 2, 4, 3, 4, 1; 3, 0, 4, 0, 1; 3, 0, 3, 1, 1; 3, 1, 4, 1, 1; 3, 1, 3, 2, 1; 3, 2, 4, 2, 1; 3, 2, 3, 3, 1; 3, 3, 4, 3, 1; 3, 3, 3, 4, 1; 3, 4, 4, 4, 1
```

I am trying to find a path between (0,0) and (3,4)

```
import collections
import math
import sys


class Graph:
    """Class to represent a Graph, as a list of weighted nodes and edges."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Function to initialize a Graph object"""
        self.node_g = {}
        self.edge_g = collections.defaultdict(list)
        pass

    def add_node(self, node_id, weight):
        """Function to add a node to a Graph object."""
        self.node_g[node_id] = weight
        print(self.node_g)
        pass

    def add_edge(self, source_id, end_id, weight):
        weightedge = (end_id, weight)
        self.edge_g[source_id].append(weightedge)
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "nodes:% s edges:% s" % (self.node_g, self.edge_g)

    def __str__(self):
        return "From str method of graph: nodes are % s, " \
               "edges are % s" % (self.node_g, self.edge_g)


def build_Graph(nodes, edges):
    """Function to build a grid-like Graph object from the input data.

    Parameters
    ----------
    nodes : list of nodes, each represented as coordinates, and node_weight.
    For example: x1, y1, weight; x2, y2, weight; ...
    edges : list of edges, each represented as source and end node coordintates, and edge_weight.
    For example: x1, y1, x2, y2, weight; x3, y3, x4, y4, weight; ...

    Return
    ----------
    A Graph object.
    """
    G = Graph()

    for n in nodes:
        aux = n.split(', ')

        temp1 = int(aux[0])
        temp2 = int(aux[1])
        temp_node = (temp1, temp2)

        G.add_node(temp_node, weight=int(aux[2]))

    for e in edges:
        aux = e.split(', ')

        temp1 = int(aux[0])
        temp2 = int(aux[1])
        temp = (temp1, temp2)

        auxn1 = int(aux[2])
        auxn2 = int(aux[3])
        auxn = (auxn1, auxn2)

        G.add_edge(temp, auxn, weight=int(aux[4]))

    return G


def print_output(nodes):
    """Function to print the shortest path between the two nodes with the highest weigths.
    Parameters
    ----------
    nodes : list of list of nodes (represented as: tuples of coordinates).
    """

    # nodes = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]
    # Expected output: x1, y1->x2, y2->x3, y3


def astar_shortest_path(G, source_id, end_id, heuristic):
    """Function to return the shortest path between two nodes in a Graph"""
    open_set = [source_id]
    #print(open_set)
    closed_set = []
    g = 0
    h = heuristic(source_id, end_id)
    f = g + h
    #print(G.edge_g[open_set[0]][0])
    #print(G.edge_g[source_id])
    #print(G.edge_g[end_id])
    while len(open_set) > 0:
        if source_id == end_id:
           return closed_set
        for index, item in enumerate(G.edge_g[open_set[0]]):
            print(item)
            var = item[0]
            print(var)
            if not index:
                next = item[0]
                g_next = item[1]
                h_next = heuristic(item[0], end_id)
                f_next = h_next + g_next
                if f_next < f:
                    f += f_next
                    h += h_next
                    g += g_next
                open_set.append(next)
                print(open_set)
                closed_set.append(open_set[0])
                print(closed_set)
                open_set.remove(open_set[0])
                print(open_set)
            else:
                next_2 = item[0]
                g_next_2 = item[1]
                h_next_2 = heuristic(item[0], end_id)
                f_next_2 = g_next_2 + h_next_2
                if f_next_2 < f:
                    f += f_next_2
                    h += h_next_2
                    g += g_next_2
                closed_set.append(open_set[0])
                print(closed_set)
                open_set.remove(open_set[0])
                print(open_set)
                open_set.append(next_2)
                print(open_set)


    #print(open_set)




def heuristic(a, b):
    #print(a, b)
    """Function to compute the Euclidean distance between two nodes."""
    dx = abs(b[0] - a[0]) ** 2
    #print(dx)
    dy = abs(b[1] - a[1]) ** 2
    #print(dy)
    return math.sqrt(dx + dy)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read the input
    # The first line is made of a list of nodes, written as tuples of cartesian coordinates.
    # For example: x1, y1, weight; x2, y2, weight; ...
    # In the previous example, x1, y1, weight; is the first node
    nodes = input().split('; ')
    # The second line is made of edges, written as source and end node coordinates, and edge_weight.
    # For example: x1, y1, x2, y2, weight; x3, y3, x4, y4, weight; ...
    # In the previous example, x1, y1, x2, y2, weight; is the first edge
    edges = input().split('; ')

    # Build a grid graph from the input nodes and edges
    G = build_Graph(nodes, edges)
    print(G)
    sort_edge = sorted(G.node_g, key=G.node_g.get)
    max1 = sort_edge[-2]
    #print(max1)
    max2 = sort_edge[-1]
    #print(max2)

    # Find the two nodes with the highest weights in the graph
    source_id = (0, 0) #max1
    end_id = (3, 4) #max2

    # Compute the path between the two nodes with the highest weight
    # The source node is the one with the highest weigth
    # You are free to customize the following function
    s_path = astar_shortest_path(G, source_id, end_id, heuristic)

    # Expected output format: list of lists of nodes (represented as: tuples of coordinates).
    # For example: x1, y1->x2, y2->x3, y3
    print_output(s_path)

    #############
```

Comment: Just a note: If you have a lot of similar statements at the start (or end) of your `if/else`, you can pull those similar lines out before (or after) the `if/else`.

Comment: @Rogue yes i know this is just like a draft program i am just trying to make the function work, do you know why it works like this? why is the else statement still executed after the first iteration even though the if statement is true

Comment: On what specific index and item do you think the if-else is doing the wrong thing?

Comment: well in the first loop it looks at coordinate 1,0 i calculate the f score, which is lower than the f score that is initialised, so the source id from the open list should move to the closed list and the 1,0 should be added to the open list, and what i want then is the for loop to start again starting from that key in the dictionary with 1,0